# SQL query to pull the document revision from a file path

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I have a document table that stores a document name and the file path.  The document revision that I need is embedded in the file path.  The revision is the last character, (or last two characters), before the file extension and preceded with a dash.  The only caveat is that a document that has not been revised also uses a dash as a revision place holder.  I need to be able to extract that dash, as well.

[image]

Comment: Please include sample data as *consumable text* to make it easier to assist, [not as images](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-not-upload-images-of-code-errors-when-asking-a-question)

Comment: Stu, I am new member to this site and it is not allowing me to attach anything other than an image.  I believe it said that it will do this seven times and I am only on my second submittal.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a possible solution you can try. It's often easier to work with a *reversed* version of the string in this situation since then you always know you are starting with the file extension and so are looking for the first `.` and `-` in the string.

```
with r as (
    select urlLocation, Reverse(urlLocation) r
    from t
),
p as (
    select *,
    CharIndex ('.',r)+1 s, 
    IsNull(NullIf(CharIndex ('-',r)-charindex ('.',r)-1,0),1) l
    from r
)
select urlLocation, Reverse(Substring(r,s,l))
from p
```

[Demo DB<>Fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=582f3ec54a39042d1791d98c3e7d8f3e)